# Is there a list of monsters by plane of origin anywhere?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, planes

I’m trying to make a different kind of campaign that deals with all of the planes. I recently found out about the plane of Mechanus. Is there a list of the different planes in 5e?

More specifically I want this list for the purpose of finding monsters for the planes, such as, Modrons. The goal of this question is to be able to find monsters associated with the different planes.

Comment: So you actually want a list of planes listing all the monsters that come from them? I'm kind of confused what you are looking for here.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Yes I am. having a list of planes isn't particularly helpful without knowing what creatures inhabit the plane.

Answer (score 5):

#### There is no official source that lists monsters by plane of origin

Unfortunately, there is no resource available in any of the offical books that lists all the planes and the monsters which inhabit them. Dndbeyond also has no such ability to search or filter on this. So, I'm afraid you are going to have to do the work manually.

A good place to start though will be Appendix C of the PHB (p 300) which is called "The Planes of Existence" and which has the full list of planes:

- Material
- Feywild
- Shadowfell
- Positive
- Negative
- Ethereal
- Astral
- Earth
- Air
- Wind
- Fire
- Bytopia
- Elysium
- Beastlands
- Arborea
- Ysgard
- Limbo
- Pandemonium
- Abyss
- Hades
- Gehenna
- Nine Hells
- Acheron
- Mechanus
- Arcadia
- Mount Celestia

Though the PHB also notes that these are only the most well-known planes and that there may be others (eg Outlands) as well as demiplanes.

The PHB has a nice graphic showing the arrangement of all the planes as well which is worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes - ish

[This pdf table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ZMKHGbPt2rQm90TDc4MlNEekU/view) made for D&D 3.5e and [this compilation](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?65324-Monsters-By-Plane) made for D&D 3e, are very useful for D&D 5e as well and I intend to use them for guidance in an upcoming 5e campaign. Many creatures do not carry over directly to D&D 5e and will need to be substituted, replaced or deleted as necessary.
Some notes about the planes in these lists:

- *Elemental Plane of Cold* is called the *Frostfell* in 5e
- *Plane of Faerie* is referred to as the *Feywild* in 5e
- I can't recall seeing any mention of the *Plane of Mirrors*, *Plane of Radiance*, nor *Region of Dreams* in 5e, however that doesn't mean they don't exist, it just means they're not mentioned or I missed them or their names have been changed.
- The *Spirit World* and *Shadowlands* are from D&D 3e's *Oriental Adventures* (Wyatt, 2001) which has not been updated to 5e.  However monsters such as the Oni can exist on these planes.
- *Plane of Shadow* is called the *Shadowfell* in 5e
- Planes such as the *Plane of Radiance* were considered quasielemental planes and existed in between the elemental planes and other planes.  For example the *Plane of Radiance* existed between the *Plane of Fire* and the *Positive Energy Plane* (The Inner Planes, 1998, p 9, AD&D 2e):

  > The Quasielemental Plane of Radiance is a place of incredible light born of the union between Fire and Positive Energy.
- I haven't gone through yet to update the creatures, many of which are not listed in 5e references and some which may have undergone name changes.  Still these lists are a good start and I've found them helpful.

For a searchable database of 3e creatures you can also use [this webpage](http://monsterfinder.dndrunde.de/results.php?id=2801260407&skip=0) to search by plane of origin.